# IntelliJ live template from class type

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, live-templates

I was playing around with IntelliJ live templates and I work every day with Instancio library https://www.instancio.org/

One of the things that are a bit verbose is writing for instance:

```java
List<String> varName = Instancio.createList(String.class);
```

But at the end I also create Lists for any kind of type...

My objective was to create a live template so that when I write for instance  `Animal.ilist` it replaces that by

```java
List<Animal> varName = Instancio.createList(Animal.class);
```

The only thing that I have achieved so far is

```java
List<> varname = Instancio.createList(.class);
```

but I could not make it work for `type.ilist`

[image]

Comment: it seems to me that you are after **postfix completion** actually: 1) https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/ 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-postfix-completion.html 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#postfix_completion

Comment: Thank you so much @LazyOne I didn't know the existance of postfix-completion.
I leave here my postfix template:

final List<$EXPR$> $END$ = Instancio.createList($EXPR$.class);

Comment: Consider adding it as an answer with some comments/links/screenshot (what was used, the final solution, how it was done / how it actually works now) -- 1) it will help other users in a similar situation 2) you can accept your own answer in a few days; question with accepted answer has better visibility/discoverability than just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding the answer here so it has more visibility:

I checked the **postfix completion** which can be found on IntelliJ 2023.2 version under

*Settings* -> *Editor* -> *General* -> *PostFix Completion*

I thought I could create a new group but I ended up adding it under Java:

[image: Created template]

1. Add as a key the "Keyword" that would trigger this postfix live
   template. In my case "ilist"
2. Select the minimum language level. I left it as default.
3. Add the expression under the editable section. The $EXPR$ contains the text that was written before the "keyword".

Since $EXPR$ contains my class type I added the $EXPR$ to the result parts of my template where it was needed.

*Note: the $END$ which sets the cursor to that position after the live template is triggered* this lets you set a variable name without needing to position yourself.

Here you can see how to use it:

[image: How it works]